# Move list item to the left in header/navigation menu

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, menu, header

i'm here to beg for your help! the problem is regarding Navigation bar, and the text/links for it.
The issue is that the last list item is all the way to the right of the header, i want to move everything to the left, not to center it completly, just to be able to move it bit by bit to fit it for my purpose! 
Thanks on beforehand

```css
/* CSS below: */

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'work sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80% margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin 0;
  padding 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>navbar</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>



<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Radiostyrt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">El-fordon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kontakta oss</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Media Galleri</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


    </div>
  </header>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting a `margin-right: 50px` or something on your `nav` tag

Answer (score 0):

put `margin-right: how much you want px` on your `nav` tag, and don't forget to create a div to the logo, because if you put the `margin-right` the logo will go togheter to the left.

Comment: forget what i sad about the div.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code snippets on CSS parts for the change. I hope this is your expected output.

```css
/* CSS below: */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'work sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
nav {
  
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>navbar</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>



<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="logo1.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Radiostyrt</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">El-fordon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kontakta oss</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Media Galleri</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


    </div>
  </header>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Remove `margin: 0 auto;` in `.container` and remove `float: right;` in `nav`